# Can not remove eventListener

Tags: javascript, canvas

I make en event listener inside the chose function, but i cannot remove it in the 'win' function. (the chose function is implemented in a setInterval, but after only after calling the clearInterval)
How can i remove this event listener? I don't want the text to be changeable after i clicked.

```
function chose() {
    canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
        if (((ballPos == 1) & (event.clientX > posX1) & (event.clientX < posX1 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)) |
            ((ballPos == 2) & (event.clientX > posX2) & (event.clientX < posX2 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)) |
            ((ballPos == 3) & (event.clientX > posX3) & (event.clientX < posX3 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)))
            win = true;

        else
            win = false;
        canvas.addEventListener('click', function () {
            winpage(win);
        }, false);
    }

}

function winpage(win) {
    canvas.removeEventListener('click', function () {
        winpage(win);
    }, false);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    if (win)
        context.fillText("YOU WIN!!!", w / 2, h / 2);
    else
        context.fillText("YOU LOSE!!!", w / 2, h / 2);
}
```

Comment: Both Lalit Kumar and Krzysiek are giving you the correct answer.  To remove an event listener, the signature of the handler must be the same in both addEventListener & removeEventListener.  So you can't use an anonymous function to create the listener.  You must use the same named handler function in both the add and remove commands.  An often used alternative is to create a flag that can be set/unset to indicate whether you want certain processing to take place or not.

Answer (score 0):

It must be exactly the same function.

```
var handler = function () {
        winpage(win);
    };
function chose() {
    canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
        if (((ballPos == 1) & (event.clientX > posX1) & (event.clientX < posX1 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)) |
            ((ballPos == 2) & (event.clientX > posX2) & (event.clientX < posX2 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)) |
            ((ballPos == 3) & (event.clientX > posX3) & (event.clientX < posX3 + cupw) & (event.clientY > posY) & (event.clientY < posY + cuph)))
            win = true;

        else
            win = false;
        canvas.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    }

}

function winpage(win) {
    canvas.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    if (win)
        context.fillText("YOU WIN!!!", w / 2, h / 2);
    else
        context.fillText("YOU LOSE!!!", w / 2, h / 2);
}
```

Comment: If I used handler like this it never goes into the handler function, then I tried it like this:

`function handler(){
 winpage(win);
}`

but this way it stil doesn't remove the listener

Answer (score 0):

Create a **event listener** as below that will add and remove as you desired in your code.

```
var win;
var listener = function (event) {
    /* do something here */
    // You can also remove event here
    // As below will remove event from target element 
    // event.target.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
    winpage(win);
};
```

Add event as below

```
function chose() {
        canvas.onmousemove = function (event){
        if( ((ballPos == 1)&(event.clientX > posX1)&(event.clientX < posX1+cupw)&(event.clientY > posY)&(event.clientY < posY+cuph)) |
                ((ballPos == 2)&(event.clientX > posX2)&(event.clientX < posX2+cupw)&(event.clientY > posY)&(event.clientY < posY+cuph)) |
                ((ballPos == 3)&(event.clientX > posX3)&(event.clientX < posX3+cupw)&(event.clientY > posY)&(event.clientY < posY+cuph)))
            win = true;

        else
            win = false;
        canvas.addEventListener('click',listener, false);}
}
```

And remove event as below

```
winpage = function(win) {
    canvas.removeEventListener('click',listener, false);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    if (win)
       context.fillText("YOU WIN!!!",w/2,h/2);
    else
       context.fillText("YOU LOSE!!!",w/2,h/2);
}
```

Always have a event listener reference for adding and removing it from desired dom element.

Read full documentation on [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)  and [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/EventTarget.removeEventListener) . See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3pc9L/).

Comment: thanks, tried it, but now it doesn't even react to clicking, perhaps its remove the even listener before it. Any tips for this?

Comment: Check you handler method and you must write a logic that when you are going to remove and add it again for action. Can I see your new code after modification?